# One of two animations doesn't work on page load jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, coffeescript

I'm trying to get both lines of text on the page to animate in on page load. However, the top line works just fine but the bottom one won't show up at all. Can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
<div id="welcome_intro">
    <h3 id="welcome">Welcome</h3>
    <h1 id="apples">apples</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h3, h1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Coffeescript:

```
$ -> 
    $("#welcome").slideDown(1000);
    $("#apples").slideUp(1050);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jz76cra/

Comment: The `#apples` are already hidden, and you can't slide up something that is hidden

Comment: Oh I thought slideup was just the same effect as slidedown but in the opposite direction - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to animate it, either *up* or *down* then have *down* because *up* have it hidden so you will not be able to see it. Try this:

```
$("#welcome").slideDown(1000);
$("#apples").slideDown(1050);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @adeneo said, you can't slide up what's already hidden, but in case you want a delay on the second div, you can always add jQuery delay or timeout on it.

```
    $("#welcome").slideDown(1000);
    $("#apples").delay(1000).slideDown(1050);
```

Just like that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jz76cra/1/)